# Difference in optimization between query call inside own application and the advances database architect

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I am working at the moment with the advantage database server from sybase. I am programming in delphi and I am using a local server. My problem is, if I make a sql query inside my own source code the query is 3 times slower (especially for nested Select queries) as if I would use exactly the same query inside the Advantage Database Architect delivered by sybase, too. 
The database is also the same. Is there any optimization step I am missing?

My Source Code looks like this:

```
  //Initializing Connection and Query
  FADSConnection.LoginPrompt := false;
  FADSConnection.ConnectPath := Filename;
  FADSConnection.AdsServerTypes := [stADS_LOCAL];
  FADSConnection.Name := 'ADB';
  FADSConnection.EncryptionOptions.DataEncryptionType := etAdsAES256;
  FADSConnection.IsConnected := true;


  FADSQuery.DatabaseName := FADSConnection.Name;
  FADSQuery.SourceTableType := ttAdsADT;
  FADSQuery.AdsTableOptions.AdsCharType := GERMAN_VFP_CI_AS_437;

  s := 'SELECT *' 
       + 'FROM ADB_Table1 WHERE No IN' 
       +'(SELECT No' 
       +       'FROM ADB_Table2 WHERE V=0.4 AND N=26 AND No IN' 
       +       '(SELECT No FROM ADB_Table2 WHERE V=0.6 AND N=8)) AND Count=2'

  FADSQuery.sql.Text := s;
  FADSQuery.Open;
  FADSQuery.first;
```

The Query takes 600 ms in my program. In the advantage database architect it needs 200 ms. The database has around 18000 entries.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you measure the runtime in your program? The difference may be due to different measuring.

Comment: It seems you're using a data dictionary. Have you tried to put the query into a view and running that from ARC and your program?

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff I think it's not the problem of measuring. Cause it feels also longer, if I change the search criteria a little bit, that in the architect the query is taking 2 s and in my program 10 s. have not tried the view yet, but I will do so and report.

Comment: ARC only measures the time it takes to fill the grid for the display. If you measure the time to process the whole result set in your application, then that could be reason for the difference.

Comment: I agree with Alex.  Also, remember that with local server (especially if DB on a different machine) that multiple users will slow down access.  When you run your program is ARC still connected or vice versa is the app still connected when using ARC?  See KB 980901-0452 on the devzone.advantagedatabase.com

Comment: No I always just run one program at a time. The database is actually not for multi user purpose.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I need for an SQL search in ARC 1/10 time less than in my delphi program. Is there any optimization step I have to do before starting the connection or the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found my mistake:

The Problem is the initialization of the query instance.
Somehow overhanding of the Source Table Type and the AdsCharType isn't necessary.

```
FADSQuery.SourceTableType := ttAdsAdt;
FADSQuery.Tableoptions.AdsCharType := GERMAN_VFP_CI_AS_437;
```

I just removed the above lines and my queries are nearly as fast as the Advantage Data Architect.